# Convert video while uploading

Tags: php, ffmpeg

I want to convert a video (say from wmv format to flv) while a user uploads it. I can either convert a video or upload it individually, but how to do them at once?

Iam using ffmpeg for conversion, like:

> ffmpeg -i WMV.wmv WMV.flv

But iam unsure about the steps to be followed to convert and upload a video. Do i need to use Ajax or something like that?

Comment: You mean, *while the bytes are streaming from the user's computer to the server*, you want to convert it?

Comment: Anyways, its ok. Whether while bytes are streaming, or after the video is uploaded.

Comment: I think you need some sort of scheduled job (ie via crontab). The convert process can takes very long time and you don't want "hang" the user in front of a very long loading page

Comment: Ok, seems good. What iam planning is: when a user uploads a video in wmv format, first it will be saved to a folder(in wmv format) and simultaneously it will be inserted into the database with its filename. Later, in admin panel, the admin can click on convert button and it will be converted into flv using ffmpeg. How would be this process ?

Comment: Do one thing when user upload video then on server side convert video and save.For batch video processing sheduling of task may be prefferred as it can cause quite a time!

Comment: I prefer this... first admin uploads the wmv video, and its name and path are saved into the database. Later, admin views the videos list and he can convert them by clicking on a link, and after conversion is over, he can enable that flv video. Then users can watch that flv video.

Comment: if it is an admin side then why the issue you can set that video to be right at the time of upload! if the section involved any client side then only issue of page loading for long time issue occur.

Comment: Yes, it is admin's job... but i confused with the task of uploading and converting at once... now i think its better to upload first and then convert later and enable it... because the conversion can also take time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

FFMPEG is a pretty powerful plugin

For PHP side execution example

```
<?php

     /*** convert video to flash ***/
     exec("ffmpeg -i video.wmv -ar 22050 -ab 32 -f flv -s 320x240 video.flv");

?>
```

The terms used

```
 -i Input file name
 -ar Audio sampling rate in Hz
 -ab Audio bit rate in kbit/s
 -f Output format
 -s Output dimension
```

To know the advanced uses of FFMPEG Check the link

[FFmpeg Tricks You Should Know About](http://segfault.in/2010/10/ffmpeg-tricks-you-should-know-about/)