# Save uploaded file in 2 extentions php

Tags: php, video, file-upload

I want to let my users upload a video (and after uploading watching it). The video is saved on the server. However, to let every user watch the video with `<video>`, I have to make sure I offer the video in 2 extensions, namely .ogg and .mp4 [see www.w3schools.com](http://www.w3schools.com/TAgs/tag_video.asp).

how do I save the same file twice, but with different extensions, and how to convert them to the other extension in php?

I thank you for your time.

Comment: have you tried anything? - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4803101/convert-video-while-uploading

Comment: You can not just safe the same file with different extensions. You need to have 2 different files. So the user either needs to upload them both or you need to convert them. To convert you need something like [ffmpeg](http://www.ffmpeg.org/) I believe